# Login loop revisited

Tags: unity, permissions, xorg, login, lightdm

I'm using 14.04 LTS Desktop on a Lenovo laptop and it's been working great until this morning. After a reboot I encountered the login loop, where you log in and immediately return to the login screen. I've found many solutions on this and other forums, all of them point to ownership of .Xauthority and such. Unfortunately, none of them have solved the problem for me.

Running ls -la form a tty reveals there is no .Xauthority file at all. None.

To make matters worse $XAUTHORITY is not set for any user including root.

(I do have an .ICEauthority with correct permissions in my home directory.)

I've tried restarting unity by restarting lightdm service from a tty, but that did not result in an .Xauthority file getting created as suggested elsewhere.

I've tried running startx from tty, and I do get a .Xauthority file with correct permissions etc. However the problem persists. As soon as I do a GUI log in I'm returned to the login screen. Same for all users, including guest account.

How can I fix this? (Short of reinstalling - I have too much stuff installed on this machine to make that a viable options.)

Comment: I don't rightly know and maybe someone does but how about we try `sudo chmod a+wt /tmp` from TTY and try again? It won't break anything - I just want to make sure the permissions are correct before speculating. That it is even on the guest account makes me focus on this - but I'm not certain.

Comment: Can you remember what you did yesterday (before the login loop problem started)? Everything you did as root or with sudo can be important, even if it doesn't seem related.

Comment: Byte Commander - The last thing I did was check email with thunderbird. I believe that an update was running before that, so that would have been a sudo. Can't for the life of me remember what was updated.

Comment: KGIII - Thanks for response. I ran the command. Made no difference unfortunately. Please go ahead and speculate now. :-)

Comment: By the way just for grins and giggles I added another user from the command line. That user has an .Xauthority in the home directory. Unfortunately that user has the same issue.